# Does google colab permanently change file

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am doing some data pre-processing on Google Colab and just wondering how it works with manipulating dataset. For example R does not change the original dataset until you use `write.csv` to export the changed dataset. Does it work similarly in colab? Thank you!

Comment: The way I/O works depends on what library you are using to manipulate your data. Which one do you have in mind?

Comment: Hi Bob,  I am currently using `pandas`, `numpy` and `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you explicitly save your changed data, e.g. using `df.to_csv` to the same file you read from, your changed dataset is not saved.

You must remember that due to inactivity (up to an hour or so), you colab session might expire and all progress be lost.

**Update**

1. To download a model, dataset or a big file from Google Drive, [gdown](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/) command is already available

`!gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID`

2. Download your code from GitHub and run predictions using the model you already downloaded

`!git clone https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/username/project.git`

3. Write ! before a line of your code in colab and it would be treated as bash command. You can download files form internet using `wget` for example

`!wget file_url`

4. You can commit and push your updated code to GitHub etc. And updated dataset / model to Google Drive or Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @eMad. Do you know what I need to do to apply a machine learning model which is written in another file on a new dataset for prediction(in terms of saving/downloading the files)? Cheers

Comment: Hi @nilsinelabore, I've updated the answer. Let me know if something still doesn't make sense